# Is it possible to update the UI from different thread besides the Main Thread in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, java-native-interface

I'm having some rough time trying to figure a way arround this problem. I have an Activity, but the UI is too slow to render the entire screen because it is running on the Main thread. I have two main sections to render, and wanted to use a separate thread to render one of those two sections. My questions are:

- Is it possible to update the UI in an activity from a separate thread? If so how?
- Is it possible to update the UI from code done in C++ and on a different thread?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "the UI is too slow to render the entire screen because it is running on the Main thread" -- what are you trying to render? Is this a regular `View` hierarchy? Is this something being implemented in OpenGL?

Comment: I'm rendering a grid with several images. I'm using a normal activity using Java.

Answer (score 0):

> the UI is too slow to render the entire screen because it is running on the Main thread

Use Traceview and `StrictMode` to determine where your problem really lies. For example, since you are "rendering a grid with several images", unless the images are already in memory, the loading of the images should be done on a background thread. There are countless libraries, like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), that offer this.

> Is it possible to update the UI in an activity from a separate thread?

Generally speaking, no. And usually that's not the problem -- the problem comes when trying to load model data, such as your images, on the main application thread.

> Is it possible to update the UI from code done in C++ and on a different thread?

Generally speaking, no, for a `View`-centric UI as you describe. I assume OpenGL can use multiple threads for rendering, but OpenGL is not my area.

Comment: @IndieDG: Then use Traceview to determine where you are spending your time.